# AWS DynamoDB scan CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to do this scan:

[image]

Through CLI:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name dev-XXX-transactions --select "*" --filter-expression "#idXXXTransaction = :idXXXTransaction" --expression-attribute-names "{\"#idXXXTransaction\": \"idXXXTransaction\"}"
```

But I'm not sure how can I do an "EXISTS" on a attribute, I know how to make an exact match. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is specified by the `attribute_exists()` function. I believe your filter expression should be `attribute_exists(idXXXTransaction)`.

The available expression operators and functions are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).